# Can I use the airtrain from JFK if I'm not flying?

Tags: jfk

I'm going to pick up someone from JFK terminal 1. I wanted to know whether I can use the AirTrain from any terminal on JFK to Jamaica station? Can I go through the terminal and use the AirTrain even if I'm not flying in or out of JFK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  The AirTrain is accessible to anyone, regardless of whether you are flying or not.

As with all passengers, you will need to pay for the ride if you are travelling to Jamaica station.